# маленькие изображения в Lightbox

Tags: javascript, html, lightbox

Создал модальное окно с помощью LightBox, но изображение очень маленькое,а разрешение у изображения большое[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кусок кода, относящийся к проблеме, выложите, пожалуйста.

Comment: В принципе, если я беру любой jQuery плагин ( fancybox, lightbox ), то он такого типа картинки делает очень маленькими

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хотя и непонятно, каким именно лайтбоксом вы пользуетесь, но очевидно, что сейчас он настроен на то, чтобы выводимое изображение полностью помещалось в экран. Данное изображение слишком большое по высоте, чтобы поместиться в экран, потому оно пропорционально сжимается по ширине. Чтобы это исправить в, например, плагине [Lightbox by Lokesh Dhakar](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) необходимо задать для свойства `fitImagesInViewport` значение `false`.

Comment: Есть такое. При параметре false картинка обретает нереальных размеров ) А как сделать, чтобы по высоте она создавала скролл вниз, а по ширине было на 90%?

Comment: Для ширины там есть свойство `maxWidth`, а что касается скролла, то это вам надо самостоятельно для обертки изображения задать через CSS `max-height: 500px; overflow: scroll;`.

Comment: Сделал это все) Спасибо. Вот только скрипт сам делает left:0 , а мне надо 50%

Comment: Выровнял все. осталось разобраться , как исходящие настройки вернуть , если ширина меньше 620px